# In this code the variable isn't actually changing, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the variable playersTurn and it is just not changing values can someone tell me why? I have tried using alerts to find where the code is going wrong I have wrote the code multiple ways why wont this var update? Everything else is working as it should except this variable.

```
    <div class="square p1">1</div>
    <div class="square p1">2</div>
    <div class="square p1">3</div>
    <div class="square p1">4</div>
    <div class="square p1">5</div>
    <div class="square">6</div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: #ff0000;">7</div>
    <div class="square">8</div>
    <div class="square p2">9</div>
    <div class="square p2">10</div>
    <div class="square p2">11</div>
    <div class="square p2">12</div>
    <div class="square p2">13</div>
    <div class="square p1">14</div>
    <div class="square p1">15</div>
    <div class="square p1">16</div>
    <div class="square p1">17</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #8b4513;">18</div>
    <div class="square">19</div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: #ff0000;">20</div>
    <div class="square">21</div>
    <div class="square p2">22</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #8b4513;">23</div>
    <div class="square p2">24</div>
    <div class="square p2">25</div>
    <div class="square p2">26</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #008000;">27</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #008000;">28</div>
    <div class="square p1">29</div>
    <div class="square p1">30</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #8b4513;">31</div>
    <div class="square">32</div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: #ff0000;">33</div>
    <div class="square">34</div>
    <div class="square p2">35</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #8b4513;">36</div>
    <div class="square p2">37</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #008000;">38</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #008000;">39</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #008000;">40</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #008000;">41</div>
    <div class="square p1">42</div>
    <div class="square p1">43</div>
    <div class="square p1">44</div>
    <div class="square">45</div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: #8b4513;">46</div>
    <div class="square">47</div>
    <div class="square p2">48</div>
    <div class="square p2">49</div>
    <div class="square p2">50</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #008000;">51</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #008000;">52</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #008000;">53</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #008000;">54</div>
    <div class="square p1">55</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #8b4513;">56</div>
    <div class="square p1">57</div>
    <div class="square">58</div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: #ff0000;">59</div>
    <div class="square">60</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #8b4513;">61</div>
    <div class="square p2">62</div>
    <div class="square p2">63</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #008000;">64</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #008000;">65</div>
    <div class="square p1">66</div>
    <div class="square p1">67</div>
    <div class="square p1">68</div>
    <div class="square p1" style="background-color: #8b4513;">69</div>
    <div class="square p1">70</div>
    <div class="square">71</div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: #ff0000;">72</div>
    <div class="square">73</div>
    <div class="square p2" style="background-color: #8b4513;">74</div>
    <div class="square p2">75</div>
    <div class="square p2">76</div>
    <div class="square p2">77</div>
    <div class="square p2">78</div>
    <div class="square p1">79</div>
    <div class="square p1">80</div>
    <div class="square p1">81</div>
    <div class="square p1">82</div>
    <div class="square p1">83</div>
    <div class="square">84</div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: #ff0000;">85</div>
    <div class="square">86</div>
    <div class="square p2">87</div>
    <div class="square p2">88</div>
    <div class="square p2">89</div>
    <div class="square p2">90</div>
    <div class="square p2">91</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var p1Setup = 9;
        var p2Setup = 9;
        var playersTurn = "p1";
        function update() {
            if(playersTurn == "p1") {
                p1PlaceUnits();
            }
            if(playersTurn == "p2") {
                p2PlaceUnits();
            }
        }
        function p1PlaceUnits() {
            $(".p1").click(function() {
                if(p1Setup > 0) {
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('unitPlaced-p1')) {
                        $(this).addClass("unitPlaced-p1");
                        p1Setup--;
                        //alert("Player 2's turn.");
                        playersTurn = "p2";
                        update();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function p2PlaceUnits() {
            $(".p2").click(function() {
                if(p2Setup > 0) {
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('unitPlaced-p2')) {
                        $(this).addClass("unitPlaced-p2");
                        p2Setup--;
                        //alert("Player 1's turn.");
                        playersTurn = "p1";
                        update();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Here is a link to the site if you want to inspect the code [War Pit](http://timothy.techbytbone.com/war_pit.php)

Comment: You don't need the `else` statements if they aren't doing anything. Also, what is your question? Should `playersTurn` toggle? What should happen to `playersTurn`?

Comment: your if statements arent inside any event, when are they being called?

Comment: Yes the playersTurn should be toggling see in each function I am changing the value? also pedro I just tried putting them into a function going to test it now

Comment: Also, could you post your html as well?

Comment: I added in the html and updated the code to what I have currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is evaluated only once, so when you test the variable `playersTurn`, it always be true at first time. When you click on a `.p1` or `.p2` the code that test the variable `playersTurn` is not evaluated again

Comment: Ok how would I keep checking the value of the variable I put the code here

while (setup == true) {
                if(playersTurn === true) {
                    p1PlaceUnits();
                    document.write(p1Turn + "<br>");
                    document.write(p2Turn + "<br>");
                }
                if(playersTurn === false) {
                    p2PlaceUnits();
                    document.write(p1Turn + "<br>");
                    document.write(p2Turn + "<br>");
                }
            }

in a while loop as you can see but it is still not working.

Comment: Can you give me a example on how to update the variable? do I put it a  loop? or something else?

Comment: With this `while` the code never hit the two last functions `p1PlaceUnits` and `p1PlaceUnits`. You can create a function for update. So you when you change the variable `playersTurn` you call this function.

Comment: I updated my code I believe it is close but can you take a look and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Yeah, try to use JsFiddle, it helps to help =D

Comment: I made other changes, I think it is more simple, try yourself [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SXjSe/2/)

Comment: I've changed the css for test purpose

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your JS to be super efficient! OVER 9000!!!!!!

```
var setup = {
    p1: 9,
    p2: 9
}
var playersTurn = "p1";

$('.square').click(function () {
    if (setup[playersTurn] > 0 && !$(this).hasClass('unitPlaced-' + playersTurn) && $(this).hasClass(playersTurn)) {
        $(this).addClass('unitPlaced-' + playersTurn);
        setup[playersTurn]--;
        (playersTurn == "p1") ? playersTurn = "p2" : playersTurn = "p1";
    }
});
```

Here you can see it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SXjSe/4/

Comment: There can only  be one answer haha ;)